# Linearity of Expectation Derivation

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

I'm trying to understand how to prove linearity of expectation. The explanation I'm reading is:

$$E[X+aY] = \int_{(x,y)}(x+ay)p_{X,Y}dxdy$$
$$= \int_{(x,y)}xp_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy + a\int_{(x,y)}yp_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$$
$$= \int_{(x)}xp_{X}(x)dx + a\int_{(y)}yp_{Y}(y)dy$$

I'm having trouble intuitively understanding how to go from the first to the second step. Mathematically why is it that I only need to worry about the PDF of $X$, and $Y$ for their respective parts rather than the joint $X,Y$ PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is your aim to prove linearity of expectation then you better go this route:$$\mathbb E [X+aY]=\int X(\omega)+aY(\omega)\mathsf P(d\omega)=$$$$\int X(\omega)\mathsf P(d\omega)+a\int Y(\omega)\mathsf P(d\omega)=\mathbb EX+a\mathbb EY$$Note that this is valid also if there is no PDF. In fact the distributions that are involved have no added value here and are left aside.

---

**edit**

Concerning your effort:

Note that $\mathbb Ef(X,Y)=\int_{(x,y)}f(x,y)p_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$ for every measurable function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$.

If you take the function $f$ prescribed by $(x,y)\mapsto x$ then you find $$\mathbb EX=\mathbb Ef(X,Y)=\int_{(x,y)} f(x,y)p_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy=\int_{(x,y)} xp_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$$

So in order to prove that $\mathbb E[X+aY]=\mathbb EX+a\mathbb EY$ it is already enough to observe that:$$\int_{(x,y)} [x+ay]p_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy=\int_{(x,y)} xp_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy+a\int_{(x,y)} yp_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy=\mathbb EX+a\mathbb EY$$

Also we have equalities like $\int_{(x,y)} xp_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy=\int_{(x)}xp_X(x)dx$ but in this context there is no need to get them involved.

---

The connection between $\mathsf P$ in my answer and $P_{X,Y}$ on $\mathbb R^2$ (which has been assumed to have a PDF $p_{X,Y}$ in your effort) is: $$P_{X,Y}(B)=\mathsf P(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid \langle X(\omega),Y(\omega)\rangle\in B\})=\mathsf P(\{\langle X,Y\rangle\in B\})=\mathsf P(\langle X,Y\rangle\in B)$$
The second and third equality only involve practicized abbreviations.

Comment: Could you explain what $P(dw)$ is, and a bit more detail on how this is different than the way I approached it? I'm not quite following the explanation.

Comment: If $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ is a [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) and $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is a random variable then $\int XdP$ or $\int X(\omega)P(d\omega)$ stands for the integral wrt probability measure $P$ having $X$ as integrand. A random vector $(X,Y):\Omega\to\mathbb R^2$ induces a measure $P_{X,Y}$ on $(\mathbb R^2,\mathcal B(\mathbb R^2))$. You are using this measure in order to prove linearity of expectation. That is possible, but not necessary. It can be done directly with $P$ instead of $P_{X,Y}$. This is what I am doing in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the notation as in your question:$$\int_{(y)}p_{X,Y}(x,y)dy=p_X(x)$$
and $$\int_{(x)}p_{X,Y}(x,y)dx=p_Y(y)$$
So we have $$\int_{(x,y)}xp_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy=\int_{(x)}x\left(\int_{(y)}p_{X,Y}(x,y)dy\right)dx=\int_{(x)}xp_X(x)dx$$
and similarly for the other integral. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. I'm having a really hard time wrapping my head around multivariate distribution PDFs and double integrals. It seems so clear that with one variable the probability is just the relative area under the curve, but with 2 im having a harder time imagining this geometrically, when you're taking the integral over just one of the variables. How come an indefinite integral over y for P_X,Y is P_X(x)? Also, for the last line how are you able to "split up" the double integral like that? Are there rules for this kind of thing?

Comment: The integrals are all definite, and we can always split the integral as I have done, so we can just integrate over $y$ first and then $x$.